# How to instruct IIS to use environment variable from web.config, to run the .net core application?

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

Recently, I'm facing a strange issue while hosting .net core 2.2 application on IIS.

After hosting, I get "*An error occurred while starting the application*". In order to identify the root cause I enabled the log file and found that its because of environment variable issue.

I configured the environment variable in my `web.config` file as like below,

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PctrClient.Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
    <environmentVariables>
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseIISIntegration();
}
```

But web app interprets it as `Development;Development`. How is it possible?

Info from **log file**

> info Hosting environment: Development;Development

Comment: Are you sure it's not just being written to your log incorrectly?

Comment: yes I'm sure because I got his info by setting `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` in the web.config file

Comment: Even if it was, that shouldn't cause the error you see.

Comment: Actually I read some config information from `appsettings.development.json` file, since IIS interprets environment variable as  `Development;Development` the actual `appsettings.development.json` file not get loaded into the application. because of that I get NULL reference exception when I try to access the config information which in `appsettings.development.json` file, while starting the application.

Comment: Then you should fix that problem first.

Comment: Also Note, If I remove the environment variable from web.config file, its working fine. I'm not sure where IIS reads the environment variable other than web.config file

Comment: Yes I agree, I have to fix that NULL reference exception, but how to load proper appsettings file based on environment variable mentioned in the web.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue, we have to set the environment variable either in `system` level or in `web.config` file. (if we set the environment variable in both places, it will get appended by .net core 2.2 framework)

From my perspective, it looks like a strange behavior, so I have raised this issue in [GitHub/AspNetCore](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6140) to know other community users thoughts, hope this issue will get addressed soon.

Answer (score 0):

i have got problems about IIS and i changed applicationHost.config with   tags. now i can use same IIS with different env. for each web app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can try your suggestion as well. Actually I have configured the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in my system as well as in `web.config` file. When I removed the environment variable from my system or from web.config file, application works fine. It looks like, .net core 2.2 concatenate the system and web.config environment variables. I created the issue for the same in .net core github repository. I will post my response, Once I get the response from them.